# Is there !important type rule for javascript / jQuery like CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering is there any `!important` type rule where default javascript, jQuery plugin particular part can be override without hacking the plugin.

in CSS it can be done like to override default values

```
p {
    color: red !important; //it override default p color
}
```

But if in jQuery a particular portion needs to be modified for any reason how it can be done without altering the original code.

e.g

Following is the piece of code from `tweecool.js` plugin and there is no option to add tweeter icon with each tweet,

```
wInner.append('<li>' + pIMG + '<div class="tweets_txt">' + field.text.replace(urlpattern, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>').replace(usernamepattern, '<a href="https://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>').replace(hashpattern, '<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23$1" target="_blank">#$1</a>') + media + ' <span>' + timestamp + '</span></div></li>');
```

So i added the `<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>` inside main plugin and it worked

```
wInner.append('<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> <li>' + pIMG + '<div class="tweets_txt">' + field.text.replace(urlpattern, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>').replace(usernamepattern, '<a href="https://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>').replace(hashpattern, '<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23$1" target="_blank">#$1</a>') + media + ' <span>' + timestamp + '</span></div></li>');
```

So wondering is there any other way without modifying the original plugin and just override the particular part where need or required modification / changes?

Comment: sorry... there is none.... also your html is invalid need to add the icon inside the `li` element

Comment: .. oh no. /*facepalm/*

Comment: @Shehary: I could be wrong but couldn't you use `.setAttribute()` of vanilla JS and modify the `style` attribute directly?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Everything you can do in HTML/CSS, you can do with JS as well by manipulation the DOM/CSSOM. Are you looking for an inline `!important` style?

Comment: @everybody, question is that is there any `!important` type of rule to use to override the default code in jQuery, not necessary that it must be `!important` point is that no need to modify the original `function` just a way to override it

Comment: @ArunPJohny i need the icon outside the `li` it's design requirement, and its working and rendered correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are attempting to override a method, correct? You can extend or override jQuery methods by using [extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/) method.

A simple example would be;

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    methodName: function() {
        // your custom code here   
    }    
});
```

Comment: minor, but this is overriding the method, not overloading.  Overloading is the ability to have multiple methods with the same name, each with different arguments